# Is there a name for this pattern where you store a callback that returns a call back?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, callback, redux

I'm trying to learn Redux/Angular from a tutorial and wondering if there's a name for this pattern I just started to understand.

This is the full file description but the pattern I'm trying to identify is over the connection between these lines:

Use the subscribe method and pass in a callback function():

```
let unsub = SUPER_STORE.subscribe(()=> {
    console.log('subs : ', SUPER_STORE.getState())
});
```

Subscribe method pushes a listener and returns a callback to remove the listener:

```
subscribe(listener: ListenerCallback): UnsubscribeCallback {
    this._listeners.push(listener);

    return () => { // returns an "unsubscribe" function
        this._listeners = this._listeners.filter(l => l !== listener);
    };
}
```

The dispatch method handles these callbacks by looping over every _listeners in the collection.

```
this._listeners.forEach((listener: ListenerCallback) => listener());
```

I've never seen this pattern of passing in  callback that returns a new callback to call for later.

### **QUESTION:**

**Is there a name for this pattern? if so, what is it?**

**FULL JS:**

```
interface Action {
    type: string;
    payload?: any;
}

interface Reducer<T> {
    (state:T, action:Action): T
}

interface ListenerCallback {
    (): void;
}

interface UnsubscribeCallback {
    (): void;
}


class Store<T> {
    private _state:T;
    private _listeners: ListenerCallback[] = [];

    constructor(private reducer:Reducer<T>, initState) {
        this._state = initState;
    }

    getState():T {
        return this._state;
    }

    dispatch(action: Action): void {
        this._state = this.reducer(this._state, action);
        this._listeners.forEach((listener: ListenerCallback) => listener());
    }

    subscribe(listener: ListenerCallback): UnsubscribeCallback {
        this._listeners.push(listener);
        return () => { // returns an "unsubscribe" function
            console.log('unsubscribe');
            this._listeners = this._listeners.filter(l => l !== listener);
        };
    }
}



const SUPER_REDUCE:Reducer<number> = (state:number, action:Action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'INCREMENT':
            return state + 1;
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

const INCREMENT_ACTION:Action = {type: 'INCREMENT'};

const SUPER_STORE = new Store<number>(SUPER_REDUCE, 0);

let unsub = SUPER_STORE.subscribe(()=> {
    console.log('subs : ', SUPER_STORE.getState())
});

SUPER_STORE.dispatch(INCREMENT_ACTION); // 0
SUPER_STORE.dispatch(INCREMENT_ACTION);  // 1
SUPER_STORE.dispatch(INCREMENT_ACTION);  // 2
SUPER_STORE.dispatch(INCREMENT_ACTION);  // 4

unsub(); // 'unsubscribe'
```

Comment: Pub/Sub? Every time you are dealing with events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pubsub (Publisher-Subscriber pattern)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern